# ASP.Net 4.0 Error Message - BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a ASP.Net 4.0 Web forms page that is giving me the following error on our web server

[image]

This page runs correctly on my localhost computer.  This is the only page in the web app that has this issue.  I've tried coping the contents of the \bin directory to the web server and copying the ASPX web page from my localhost to the web server.

Any thoughts as to what I would try next?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147100/error-bc30456-method-is-not-a-member-of-asp-codebehind-aspx

Comment: Sakir, your link concerns if I had a missing method in the code behind.  My question was about a problem with an attribute in the Page directive.

Comment: yes sorry I missed this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1000979.aspx?BC30456%20Theme%20is%20not%20a%20member%20of%20ASP%20default_aspx%20) thread of ASP.NET forums, it is concluded that you first need to **delete** all the pages from the bin directory and then copy it again. It might be an issue of caching here! A full refresh might be required to handle this case.

Comment: +1 Yup. If this is the issue, overwriting (aka "replace") sometimes isn't enough (differs from (DELETE and then ADD)  - I believe the concept is to force the application to re-compile/recycle (e.g. manually, changing (delete and add back) `web.config`, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me when I had two pages with the same "inherits" name.

I copied a "search" page, and renamed it "search2".  It worked great "on my machine".  :)

Next, I deployed... and got the "'Title' is not a member of" error.  My html page had Inherits="Private_Search", the exact same as the page I copied it from!  Also, the code behind was the same.

I changed that to Inherits="Private_Search2", and then in the code behind, renamed my class to Private_Search2, and now, no more errors!

If you recently copied a module, renamed it, and ran with it... check the inherits and the code behind class name.

happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! This was my issue. Slightly weirdly this broke both pages - not just the one that I'd copypasted.

Comment: this was my problem I copied the login and replace it in loginO.aspx and didn't replace the inheritance ,  .

Comment: Same symptoms.  I'd renamed a page policy.aspx to old_policy.aspx, and then wrote a new page policy.aspx.  The "inherits" under the original name remained in the old page after the renaming.  To fix, deleting the old page was insufficient.  After deleting the page, I found I had to exit visual studio, restart it, and the do "rebuild all".