# Textbox text changed postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I wanted to make my textbox in asp.net to postback every time a text it typed onto it but i cant seem to figure out how. Does any one knows? here is the code of the event handler

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtFiltrarNomeUtente.TextChanged
    If chkFiltroUtente.Checked And Me.cbxLocal.Text <> "" Then
        Me.loadFormInfo()
    End If
End Sub
```

and the textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFiltrarNomeUtente" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
```

so any ideas on how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `OnTextChanged` event to TextBox `txtFiltrarNomeUtente`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFiltrarNomeUtente" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: hi again, so i tried adding that but now i got an error saying :BC30456: 'TextBox2_TextChanged' is not a member of 'webforms_frmagendamr_aspx'.

Comment: See this post. I can happen if there is a mismatch between designer files and aspx page. Usually happens when copying or renaming pages etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147100/error-bc30456-method-is-not-a-member-of-asp-codebehind-aspx or  https://forums.asp.net/t/1000979.aspx?BC30456+Theme+is+not+a+member+of+ASP+default_aspx+